# Is it possible to identify multiple fingers?

Tags: android-fingerprint-api

If multiple fingerprints are stored in device,How to find which user is authorized. For example, if finger 1 is scanned do something, and if finger 2 is scanned, do something else?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/20

Comment: Thanks .Please upvote this if it helped you in someway so that it could help the community as well.